# dmesg email digest

Tags: kernel, logs, email, syslog, dmesg

I have a remote server which has some issues (Seem hardware related) which means that it logs `KVM` errors and then sometime later it becomes unresponsive and locked up. There is an often an early indication of it failing, in the `dmesg` log output, so I would like to know, is there a  Debian utility which can send me (daily?) digests of the `dmesg` (`/var/log/kern.log`) output?

Comment: You might consider a cron job to mail you the logs (or portions of the logs using tail/etc) that you want.

Comment: logcheck will do all logs, not just dmesg. You may also want to check if your hardware features a watchdog (or try softdog), to at least recover the remote system after it hangs.

Comment: may be it's better to use `syslog`to send `kern.info` or `kern.notice` messages to other host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've used [`logwatch`](http://www.logwatch.org/) to do exactly this. Directions on customizing it are here, titled: [HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch](http://www.stellarcore.net/logwatch/tabs/docs/HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch.html).

#### Installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install logwatch
```

#### Setup

Logwatch runs daily but can be configured to run more frequently It's typically kicked off from a crontab entry.

```
$ ls -l /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 265 Feb 28  2011 /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch
```

Customizations can go here:

```
/etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf
```

To email yourself the daily summary:

```
MailTo = me@example.com
```

If you want to add additional rules around a particular log file you can copy the existing rule file and modify as needed:

```
$ cp /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/syslog.conf \
      /etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/
```

Take a look at this section of the conf file, you can add additional rules here:

```
*ExpandRepeats
*RemoveService = talkd,telnetd,inetd,nfsd,/sbin/mingetty
*OnlyHost
*ApplyStdDate
```

#### Going further

I'd consult this tutorial titled: [Monitor System Logs with Logwatch on Debian 5 (Lenny)](https://library.linode.com/server-monitoring/logwatch/debian-5-lenny) for more details if you'd like to expand the monitoring beyond just he stock things that logwatch does out of the box.

Comment: Excellent, I used logwatch, setup was a bit different (I guess squeeze has the config packed different, had to copy from /etc/default and stuff)